# How can I correctly use Mono.Unix.UnixPipes.CreatePipes?

Tags: c#, mono

I want to communicate with a subprocess using a pipe other than stdin, stdout and stderr. I'm trying to use Mono.Unix.UnixPipes.CreatePipes for this. However, I can't find any examples and my best guess of how to use it isn't working. It seems that the child process I create with Process.Start cannot write to the inherited file handle. I am wondering if perhaps it has not actually inherited the handle at all. Here's my (reduced) code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mono.Unix;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length==0)
        {
            InvokeChildProcess(args);
        }
        else
        {
            RunAsChildProcess(args);
        }
    }
    static int InvokeChildProcess(string[] aArgs)
    {
        var childToParentPipe = Mono.Unix.UnixPipes.CreatePipes();
        var childToParentStream = childToParentPipe.Reading;
        string childHandle = childToParentPipe.Writing.Handle.ToString();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
            childHandle)
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
            };
        Process childProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
        childToParentPipe.Writing.Close();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(childToParentStream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[PARENT] Waiting for child output...");
            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write("[PARENT] Received output ({0} chars): ", output.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.WriteLine("[PARENT] Waiting for child to exit...");
            childProcess.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("[PARENT] Saw child exit with code {0}.", childProcess.ExitCode);
            return childProcess.ExitCode;
        }
    }
    static void RunAsChildProcess(string[] args)
    {
        int handle=int.Parse(args[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("[CHILD] Writing to file handle {0}.", handle);
        var pipeToParent = new Mono.Unix.UnixStream(handle);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeToParent))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Message from child.");
            writer.Flush();
            Environment.Exit(123);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output when it runs:

```
weeble@weeble-vm-oneiric32:~/dev$ mono MinimalPipeTest.exe
[PARENT] Waiting for child output...
[PARENT] Received output (0 chars): 
[PARENT] Waiting for child to exit...
[CHILD] Writing to file handle 4.

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Can not write to stream
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (System.IO.Stream)
  at Program.RunAsChildProcess (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Can not write to stream
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (System.IO.Stream)
  at Program.RunAsChildProcess (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[PARENT] Saw child exit with code 1.
weeble@weeble-vm-oneiric32:~/dev$
```

This example was compiled and run with Mono 2.10 as distributed in Ubuntu Oneiric.

What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure that the child process will be able to write to the pipe?

---

*EDIT* - It looks like Process.Start does indeed close all file descriptors in the child process except for 0, 1 and 2. See here in CreateProcess:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/io-layer/processes.c#L988

```
for (i = getdtablesize () - 1; i > 2; i--) {
    close (i);
}
```

I guess that means I can't use UnixPipes and Process.Start. Is there another way?

Comment: It depends what are you trying to achieve. Process.Start is does not give you guarantee that the newly created process would be child process and even that the notion of child process exists at all - it has to be cross platform after all. You may create thread and communicate using unnamed pipe but is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you cannot use a pipe bi-directionally here. In other words, you cannot read and write with the same pipe. You need two.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using a pipe bi-directionally here. CreatePipes creates two file descriptors, one called Reading and one called Writing. The parent process reads from Reading and the child process writes to Writing.